# How to get result from a column with combined data?

Tags: sql, mysql

data:

```
id  bb
1  14,35
2  5,11,12,125,36
3  3,23,45,15,1
4  651
5  5,1,6
6  1,7
```

For example, i wan't get id which with value '1'. So id(3,5,6) should return , but not others with '14' or '11'.

DB: Mysql

Comment: Ugh!  Your database design is **wrong**.  Please tell me the purpose of this query is to fix it?

Comment: what DB? sql server/oracle/mysql? Please add that info in the question & tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from test where find_in_set('1',bbb)
```

or

```
select * from test where bbb REGEXP '(^|,)1(,|$)'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most efficient solution but it might give you what you want off the table:

```
select id from MyTable where bb like '%,1,%' union 

select id from MyTable where bb like '1,%' union 

select id from MyTable where bb like '%,1' union 

select id from MyTable where bb like '1'
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something?

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  (id = 3) or (id = 5) or (id = 6)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this
select * from mytable where id like '14%' or '11%'